# C++ Remove first Bit

Tags: c++, bit, operation

I want to remove two bits.

Example:

**1** 0101000 **0** 0010001

Result:
0101000 0010001

How can I do this in C++ ;O?

Comment: What do you mean, "remove"? Replace with zeroes?

Comment: Use the `&` operator, such as `value &= 0x7F7F;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::bitset` or `boost::dynamic_bitset`